# Can I mention that the article is extremely short in a query to the editor?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals

Every advice on query letters to editors on the status of a manuscript after months of silence says not to sound demanding, impatient, not to give the editor motive for disliking you, etc.
I’ve got a manuscript on logic that’s barely over 2000 words, takes 25 minutes to read, and has supposedly been under review for 3 months. Is it ok if I mention how short the article is and how long it takes to read it in my query to the editor? If so, how would you phrase it?

Comment: Three months is not that long, be patient.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- So, not even A letter?

Comment: I would not send a letter after three months, no. But, I'm not in logic.

Comment: I'm in math (not logic), and I wouldn't send a message checking on even the shortest manuscript until at least six months.

Comment: *takes 25 minutes to read* Does it also take 25 minutes to understand? If yes, then could it be too simple to publish? If no, then taking longer to review seems more plausible.

Comment: @Allure Could be, but if it’s too simple to publish you would get to that conclusion in less than 3 months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't do that. The editor has seen the article and isn't under any misconceptions. Three months isn't actually very long for some things and there might be complexities that require deep understanding as there can be in math.

There are lots of reasons for delay, including finding suitable reviewers as well as the workload of those reviewers.

I'd suggest you relax for a while or make a query about progress without saying things that might seem offensive.

Comment: The 3 months are under review, so after they found reviewers.

Comment: Maybe. Don't depend too much on the specific semantics of what a web process page means. Some reviewers might have later declined, some might have disagreed. The article is still in the system and not rejected. That is the important part.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I knew it wasn’t mainstream to do what I asked about, but now you are both telling me not to even send A letter after 3 months, which I thought was customary. What should I do then for an article 20,000 words long? Wait for years?

Comment: Some things take years, yes, though it isn't the norm. Reviewers do it as a service to the profession, so they need to fit it into their normal work.

Comment: I know, I’m a reviewer for several journals. That’s how I know that it can’t take more than a few days to review a 2000 word manuscript…

Comment: @user354948 I'm not in logic, but in my experience the time and effort it takes to review a paper is a complicated function that depends on whatever else I have going on, complexity of the paper, my familiarity with specifics of the topic, whether things are made explicit or left for me to work out, etc. Point is, it is far from simply proportional to the length.

Comment: @Anyon That’s a great point. I think mine is pretty straightforward, though. So how long before querying, four months?

Comment: You can make a query, just don't say things that might antagonize the editor. They might be as frustrated as you are, in fact.

Comment: I would, however, only make a query if there is some deadline that is important. Losing papers in the system is pretty rare and queries aren't going to speed things up.

Comment: @user354948 I'd hope it's straightforward to you if you wrote it, but that isn't the same thing as straightforward to someone else - maybe you've inadvertently used non-standard terminology, referred to something obliquely, written a step incorrectly yet each time you read it your mind substitutes the correct version. All of these things could make sometime take additional time to puzzle over something. Additionally, you cannot assume that any reviewer has nothing on their plate besides your paper, or that they give your paper the same priority you do.

Comment: @user354948 Also, it's very hard to find reviewers right now as people are getting fed up doing it for free.

Comment: @BryantKrause I never write steps incorrectly 

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I hope it starts getting payed as soon as possible! I would earn some…

Comment: @user354948 I review for quite a number of journals. I will tend to accept a review request if I know I will be able to complete a review within the deadline, even after dealing with any other reviews I already have to do and taking into account busy periods where I won't have any time free for reviewing. So even if reviewing the article will only take a few days, it will probably be several weeks before I am ready to spend those few days on it.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Exactly my point, several weeks is less than three months. 9 weeks is many weeks, not several.

Comment: @user354948 I would think of 9 as still "several", and "many" as more like 15. My point was, if a journal gives me a deadline of 3 months (which is normal) then I will usually accept if I know I can deliver a report within 3 months. It may well be that I wouldn't have accepted a deadline of 2 months, and won't submit a report by then, even if the paper is short.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Well, apparently I suck at math, since 3 months is 12 weeks, not just 9.